# dividing data frame and transposing in a for loop r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Hi I have a csv file that I want to split by every row, then create a new file for that row of data, then transpose that data, and then finally save the dataframe as a new csv file based on the value in the 'full_name column. I can write the straightforward code to do this for the first row, but I am clueless for when it comes to doing this over the 331 iterations or rows of my initial csv

my code (that works fine for the first row) is this:

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("~/Desktop/Monthly_Reports")

Reports <- read_csv("~/Desktop/Monthly_Reports/REPORTS MASTER - SEPT.csv")

#takes the first row subsets it and renames it based on the value in the name column
Reports1 <- Reports[1,]
Report1_Name <- Reports1$Full_Name[[1]]

#then transposes the data, and makes it easier to read as a list
Reports1 <- transpose(Reports1)
rownames(Reports1) <- colnames(Reports1)
colnames(Reports1) <- rownames(Reports1)

#then binds the list so that it can be exported as data frame and into and individual csv
Reports1 <- as.data.frame(Reports1)
Reports1 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(Reports1, as.data.frame)) 
write.csv(Reports1, paste0(Report1_Name,".csv"))
```

I want to do this 331 times for every row of data, if anybody could show me how to do this it seems so simple but i have read so many threads and website help on for loops, lapply all kinds of stuff and for some reason i'm still struggling

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the data, so I can't confirm, but something like this should work:

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("~/Desktop/Monthly_Reports")

Reports <- read_csv("~/Desktop/Monthly_Reports/REPORTS MASTER - SEPT.csv")

#takes the first row subsets it and renames it based on the value in the name column
for(i in 1:nrow(Reports)){
  Reports1 <- Reports[i,]
  Report1_Name <- Reports1$Full_Name[[1]]
  
  #then transposes the data, and makes it easier to read as a list
  Reports1 <- transpose(Reports1)
  rownames(Reports1) <- colnames(Reports1)
  colnames(Reports1) <- rownames(Reports1)
  
  #then binds the list so that it can be exported as data frame and into and individual csv
  Reports1 <- as.data.frame(Reports1)
  Reports1 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(Reports1, as.data.frame)) 
  write.csv(Reports1, paste0(Report1_Name,".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Oh mate thank you so much, I cant believe how simple that was.